# JDBC Connections Release Issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I'm using Struts2, Spring3 and Hibernate4 in my application and the app server jbossAS7. The problem is I've configured max limit in my connection pool as 20. When 20 users hit the application there is an Unable to get managed connection exception. All 20 connections are being used by just 10 users with 2 connections per user. Why is that happening?

Below is the configuration of the datasource in jboss standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/DB_NAME" pool-name="DB_POOL" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
<connection-url>jdbc:log4jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db</connection-url>
<driver-class>net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy</driver-class>
<driver>log4jdbc</driver>
<pool>
<min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
</pool>
<security>
<user-name>postgres</user-name>
<password>postgres</password>
</security>
<validation>
<validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
<background-validation>false</background-validation>
</validation>
<statement>
<prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
<share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
</statement>
</datasource>
```

Spring transaction manager configuration :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="baseTransactionProxy" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">    
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
<property name="transactionAttributes">
<props>
<prop key="insert*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-java.lang.Exception</prop>
</props>
</property> 
</bean>

<bean id="loginDTO" class="com.tcs.oss.tims.loginManagement.dto.LoginDTO" />

<bean id="loginAction" class="com.tcs.oss.tims.loginManagement.action.LoginAction" scope="prototype">
<property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAO" />
<property name="loginDTO" ref="loginDTO" />
<property name="roleBasedAction" ref="roleBasedAction"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="loginDAOImpl" class="com.tcs.oss.tims.loginManagement.dao.daoImpl.LoginDAOImpl" scope="prototype">
<property name="sessionfactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="loginDAO"parent="baseTransactionProxy" scope="prototype">
<property name="target"> <ref bean="loginDAOImpl"/> </property>
</bean>
```

Hibernate configuration :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource">
<ref bean="dataSource" />
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>      
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
</props>
</bean>
```

Datasource Config :

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/TIMS_DB"/>
</bean>
```

Sample Code:

```
public void insertIntoInstance(String id) throws Exception {
try {
Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession(); // Where the sessionfactory is from Dependency Injection
Query insertQry = session.createSQLQuery("insert into table(id)values(id)");
insertQry.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
throw e;
}
}
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"  id="WebApp_9" version="2.4">

  <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
<servlet-name>InitializerServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.tcs.oss.tims.utilities.InitializerServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

 <filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>CASFilter</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/General/*</url-pattern> 
 </filter-mapping> 
  <filter> 
<filter-name>CASFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter</filter-class> 
<init-param> 
<param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.loginUrl</param-name> 
<param-value>${CAS_LOGIN_URL}</param-value> 
</init-param> 
<init-param> 
<param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.validateUrl</param-name> 
<param-value>${CAS_PROXY_VALIDATE_URL}</param-value> 
</init-param> 
<init-param> 
  <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.serviceUrl</param-name> 
        <param-value>${LOGIN_URL}</param-value> 
</init-param> 
<init-param> 
<param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.wrapRequest</param-name> 
<param-value>true</param-value> 
</init-param> 
</filter>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

I'm not sure how the connections are managed by the spring transaction manager. For just hibernate there are connection release modes where after a transaction I can release the connection but that doesn't seem to work when I have spring transaction. Please help.

Comment: Probably your setup is wrong. What is the `org.hibernate.Transaction.JDBCTransaction` class you have why aren't you just using the `HibernateTransactionManager` from Spring? Also why are you still using the ancient `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` instead of transaction driven or aspect driven transactions (that will save you a lot of configuration). Next make sure you aren't opening connections and sessions yourself (don't use `openSession` but use `getCurrentSession`) and make sure that you aren't duplicating your beans (replacing the transactional ones).

Comment: Sorry was that a mistake. I've updated the one I'm using. And I am using getCurrentSession. What setup could possibly be wrong? Not clear about that.

Comment: Post your datasource configuration (spring) and show some code. Also as stated you are using an ancient way of driving transactions you should really consider migrating to newer ways of transaction demarcation.

Comment: I've added the datasource config. And I'll look into newer ways of transaction demaraction. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything, obviously wrong with your configuration. I suspect you are doing something in your code to not release connections. Can you add some code that uses the session or connection?

Comment: I've posted the sample code. Basically I open sessions via getCurrentSession and dont close it cause I'm hoping spring would take care of that

Comment: If your `getCurrentSession` works your transaction should work, else it would fail. (It is still not clear which transaction manager you use BTW). You don't have a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in your classpath?

Comment: HibernateTransactionManager only I'm using. I do have SessionFactoryXml. I've posted that too. I'll be refering that sessionFactory bean where ever I need.

Comment: Is there any tutorial I can refer to where I can create a proper configuration? If I use annotation driven @transactional(some have asked me to use @transactional instead of this) how exactly do I write queries with a session?

Comment: You have posted the spring configuration I asked specifically for a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` file!. Do you by any change have a `OpenSesionInViewFilter` or `*Interceptor` and make sure that you aren't loading your database beans twice, as that might result in 2 sessions instead of one (due to duplicate instances). There is no difference in how you access/use the `Session` with the ancient technology you use or `@Transactional`, the latter is way easier to configure. Can you post a configuration of your dao? And how you configured it with the `baseTransactionProxy`?

Comment: No I dont have properties or cfg files. SessionFactory bean is all I have. Have posted the configuration of the dao

Comment: Why are your beans prototype scoped? They shouldn't contain state so they should be a perfect fit for a singleton. My best guess is that you are loading the configuration twice leading to leaking connections. For starters I suggest ditching the `baseTransactionProxy` and replace it with `<tx:annotation-driven /?` and annotate your dao's with `@Transactional`. That should cut your configuration in halve. Can you add the web.xml to see where and how the configuration files are loaded.

Comment: I'm using struts2 and all I have is an Action class through which my methods get triggered. Those methods in return call the DAO interface which is implement by DAOImpl. Now I don't have service methods and where would I then place @transactional ?

Comment: On your dao. Although I would recommend introducing a service layer as currently your business logic is in your web layer next to that if you have functionality that considers multiple db calls currently you get individual transactions instead of a single transaction. Now if you have 3 operations 2 succeed and the last one fails there is no way in rolling back the initial 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a JTA transaction manager in this kind of environment.

As you are using a full-blown application server, it already has a built in transaction manager that is integrated with the data sources that you have setup (at least when you set jta="true"). Also be sure to use:

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">
     org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
</prop>
```

Your hibernate session should close automagically when the transaction is committed and release associated database connections.

And don't forget to configure the Spring JTA Tx Manager

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
```

Comment: Even then wouldn't spring handle the transactions? How do I track when my connection gets released or closed? What is the advantage of JTA in this perspective? Can you please tell?